# Git setup for file that will be branched and then call other modules

Tags: python, git, github

I have a repo that I would like to branch, say into b1 b2. It contains a file main.py that imports imported.py.  Therefore, when I change imported.py, I would like the most uptodate version to be available to both b1 and b2. I thought it might be best to create a separate git repository repo A that contains main.py and then another repo B for imported.py... but what is the standard (and preferably simple) protocol for such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you chose to create a another repository, you could make it a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) of your other repositories. But this wouldn't solve your problem of having to update it in each repository. You might be able to add a [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to the submodule, so that each time you update the submodule, you do a submodule update for each of your other repositories. 
I don't think it's worth the effort of going through all this though. It would be easier to just manually merge your changes, or write a simple bash script if you're confident.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective you have two options:

- distribute the dependency as a python package (either through pypi, or your own custom pypi, or via wheels)
- just leave the file in the same repository and do

  ```
  git checkout <other branch> -- dependency.py
  ```

Anything else will just be painful and error prone.